# MSVC 2003 doesn't see any definitions from a nested include file

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a piece of code with COM class declaration as follows:

```
#include "PathTypes.h"

MIDL_INTERFACE("552C7555-0555-4444-BA86-56CF39AAFFFF")
IPathCalc : public IUnknown
{
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetLocation(
        /* [retval][out] */ GeoLocation* pLoc) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetLocation(
        /* [in] */ GeoLocation* pLoc) = 0;
    ...
    };
```

Below is the contents of `PathTypes.h` file:

```
#if !defined(PATHCALC_TYPES_INCLUDED)
#define PATHCALC_TYPES_INCLUDED

#include "libastro/AstronomyStructs.h"

#endif
```

And the `libastro/AstronomyStructs.h` from an external cross-platform library:

```
#ifndef _ASTRONOMY_STRUCTS_INCLUDED
#define _ASTRONOMY_STRUCTS_INCLUDED

typedef struct {
    double lattitude;
    double longitude;
} GeoLocation;

...

    #endif  /* _ASTRONOMY_STRUCTS_INCLUDED */
```

When I'm trying to build this code with g++ everything goes well. That's not the case with MSVC 2003 which returns **error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'GeoLocation'**.

Seems like MSVC doesn't "see" the definitions from the `libastro/AstronomyStructs.h` file. When I replace `#include "PathTypes.h"` with `#include "libastro/AstronomyStructs.h"` the code compiles without errors.

How to make MSVC 2003 to actually "see" the definitions from the nested include files?

#### Update 1:

The file `PathTypes.h` is in the same directory as the code that includes it.

Answer (score 0):

> How to make MSVC 2003 to actually "see" the definitions from the nested include files?

That should do it - my guess is `"PathTypes.h"`  is read from a different place (do you have multiple versions on your system?). Or it could be the case of circular includes, but you can't tell from the code you posted. As is, it should work.

Note: the macro `_ASTRONOMY_STRUCTS_INCLUDED` is illegal, remove the leading underscore.

Also, note that in this case you don't need the whole definition, a forward-declaration will suffice:

```
class GeoLocation; //forward-declaration

IPathCalc : public IUnknown
{
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetLocation(
    /* [retval][out] */ GeoLocation* pLoc) = 0;
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetLocation(
    /* [in] */ GeoLocation* pLoc) = 0;
...
};
```